# What could cause my react-bootstrap modal to ignore all styling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I've got two projects, one created while following a tutorial series, and another created on my own some time afterwards and trying to follow in its footsteps. I've whittled down my problem to a barebones comparison of `index.js` in both projects.

This code is a modified `index.js` that was originally auto-generated by the project-creation command `npx create-react-app <projectname>`. The modal function is copy-pasted from the [react-bootstrap website](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) (see the "Live Demo" code).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Example />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Things I've tried:

1. **Code is identical?** It's copy-pasted, so it's identical.
2. **Dependencies not installed?** When I run `npm start` and the page loads in the browser, neither complains about missing modules, plus I've looked in both projects' `package.json` files and confirmed the same dependencies.

And yet the two projects render this identical file differently:

- Project 1:
  [image: Project 1]
- Project 2:
  [image: Project 2]

**Any ideas?**

The code is identical and the packages are the same, and yet the two projects are not rendering identically. It seems like the latter simply isn't rendering styles at all.

Comment: Look at the installation steps again you are missing something. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/ Hint: Adding the css via import or cdn. 

Comment: @MilanPatel doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I forgot to add this in the `<head>...</head>` in `index.html`. It was something small in a file that I forgot to check.

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import bootstrap, so add the following line in your `Main.js` file `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` after importing React `import React from "react";`

(your `Main.js` file can be `index.js`, `App.js` or some other name)

Like this:
[image]

Comment: I didn't import bootstrap in either project, and yet it worked in one project and not the other.

Comment: This is the correct method. If you haven't done it in previous projects, you should.